# Conditional Validation will not allow form to submit

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have the below Conditional Validation, this validation only check the cc_number when the payment_method_id is 1, so it should not validate when there is other payment_method_id being used, but problem in my view page, even if I dont select the payment method, the form will not submit to the controller, unless the cc_number is filled, is there anyway to disable this cc_number check ? thank you

```
$validator->creditCard ( 'cc_number', [ 'mc','visa' ], __ ( 'invalid card number' ), function ($context)
        {
            if ($context ['data'] ['payment_method_id'] == 1)               
             return true;
        } );
```

Comment: add `allowEmpty('cc_number')`

Comment: dont seem to work, it allows the field to be submitted, but it will not check whether the number is valid any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for wasting space in this area, i just code cakephp3.5 recently, seems that this problem can be easily solve by putting ,'novalidate' => true at the $this->Form->create method